# Passing mail object from Outlook to Excel

Tags: excel, outlook, macros, vba

I have a macro in Outlook 2010 that is triggered by a specific string in the subject line.
It then opens an instance of Excel and a workbook and runs a macro.
Everything runs okay, except I want to pass the mail object from Outlook to Excel and work with it there.
I want to keep the Outlook macros small and tidy and let Excel do the work since that's where the data is headed anyway.

I've passed objects between subs within Excel, but can't seem to do it between applications.
Thanks.

Comment: If you want to post your code, I'd take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an Excel app, call it, say xlApp, and then xlApp.Run to run the macro on a saved workbook?